# Android, SQLite, Spinner

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

how I can get ID of selected item in Spinner from Database?

I know it's onItemSelected method, but I don't how to use it.

AddActivity:

```
spSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    id = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(((SpinnerObject)spSpinner.getSelectedItem()).getDatabaseId()));
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected department with ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemSelected database id: " + id);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            }
    );
```

DatabaseHandler:

```
public ArrayList<SpinnerObject> getAllDepartments(){
    ArrayList<SpinnerObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DEPARTMENTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            list.add(new SpinnerObject (cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1)));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

in this method I insert values to database. How can I insert id, which I'm getting in Spinner to database?

```
private void insertInStudentTable(String imie, String nazwisko, int indeks, String email, String telefon) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbCreate.getWritableDatabase();

    //ContentValues data_2 = new ContentValues();

    //long idOfDepart = db.insertOrThrow("departments", null, data_2);

    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();

    data.put("imie",        imie);
    data.put("nazwisko",    nazwisko);
    data.put("indeks",      indeks);
    data.put("email",       email);
    data.put("numer",       telefon);
    data.put("dept_id",    1 ); // - here must be inserted an id of department 

    db.insertOrThrow("students", null, data);
}
```

Comment: see the last parameter passed to `onItemSelected` method

Comment: @pskink sorry, I don't know, what you mean..

Comment: you want the `id`, right? so what is the last parameter of `onItemSelected` ?

Comment: How can I get this value `int databaseId = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(((SpinnerObject)spSpinner.getSelectedItem()).getDatabaseId()));` and insert into database?

Comment: `  @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        int databaseId = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(((SpinnerObject)spSpinner.getSelectedItem()).getDatabaseId()));
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected department with ID: " + databaseId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }`

Comment: @pskink I edited my question. It's working for me, it's getting `id` but how can I put this id into another table ?

Comment: why `int databaseId = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(((SpinnerObject)spSpinner.getSelectedItem()).getDatabaseId()));` ? id is passed as a last parameter of `onItemSelected`, this is your database id

Comment: so I can write like this `id = ...`

Comment: see this: http://pastebin.com/c6e2DbYt, run it and watch the logcat

Comment: I want `id` from table ....

Comment: did you run my code? what do you see in the logcat?

Comment: I see id's : 0 and 1 why? in database are id's 1 and 2 :D

Comment: from my code? do you have only two contacts?

Comment: @pskink I edited my question, look...

Comment: so you did not run my code...

Comment: My question is: how can I retrieve this `id` to insert() method ?

Comment: where do you call insert()? i don't see it anywhere in your code...

Comment: @pskink look question...

Comment: ok here is another sample code: http://pastebin.com/0UvUi5dh, paste it into your `Activity#onCreate`, run it and watch the logcat

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.panko.bazastudentow/com.example.panko.bazastudentow.AddActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{5e3b831 2722:com.example.panko.bazastudentow/u0a57} (pid=2722, uid=10057) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS`

Comment: add permission to the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

Comment: if you cannot get it to work with built-in contacts database, [here](http://pastebin.com/U1gStfKs) you have a sample that works with real database created in java code

Comment: ok i manged to make a complete working insert case with 35 lines of code and verified that `getSelectedItemId` works ok